# Can not find products after uploading test .csv

Tags: magento-1.9, product, csv, file-upload

i have successfully uploaded a test csv but the product i am using to test does not exist in the admin panel anywhere?

Any known problems like this. I am still learning so sorry if the answer is obvious.

Any help is much appreciated!

Regards
Zako

Comment: Try to reindex and clean the cache

Comment: are you using magento default import/export to upload or magmi ?